# How to find all regions given a country name in AWS Java SDK?

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

This [class](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/regions/Region.html) provides constants for all the regions AWS supports. However instead of manually creating a list in my app for all US regions, is there a way to get all supported regions from AWS SDK itself without hardcoding in the app?
Currently i have a hacky way to filter those in the list that starts with `US_`.

Im not looking to get regions for any service. Just all the regions name strings that AWS has.

SDK Version in use: 2.21.1

Comment: Not sure you can do much better than that (inferring United States regions from `us` prefix). Also note that AWS hosts various data sets in SSM Parameter Store for region/service/endpoint etc. data. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/parameter-store-public-parameters-global-infrastructure.html).